# PIC18F45K50 Interrupts

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I am trying to write code in assembly that detects an interrupt (pushbutton) on my PIC18F45K50 and upon detecting an interrupt, an LED turns on. For some reason the microcontroller is not detecting the interrupt. I am using an INT1 interrupt (thus B1 input) and the LED is at D1.

This is my asm code:

```
INCLUDE "p18f45k50.inc"

; Aim of program: input at B1 toggles the led at D1
; Assembly source line config statements

CONFIG  WDTEN = OFF   
CONFIG LVP = OFF 
CONFIG FOSC = INTOSCIO 

begin       ORG 0
        BCF INTCON3, 0 ;clear flag INT1IF 
        CLRF LATB ;clear latB
        goto prog 

hinterrupt  ORG 0x08
        goto introutine

        ORG 0x22
prog    ;D1
        BCF ANSELD, 1 ;set D1 to digital
        BCF TRISD,1 ;configure PORTD.1 as output pin
        ;BSF PORTD, 1

        ;B1
        BCF ANSELB, 1 ;set B1 to digital
        BSF TRISB, 1 ;configure B1 as input pin 

        ;INT1 hence B1 settings
        BSF INTCON3, 6 ;set INT1 to high priority 
        BSF INTCON2, 5 ;+ve edge trigger for B1
        BSF INTCON3, 3 ;enable INT1
        BSF RCON, 7 ;set IPEN to HIGH thus enabling priorities on interrupts
        BSF INTCON, 7 ;set GIEH to high, enabling high priority interrupts


        goto prog


introutine  BCF INTCON3, 0 ;clear flag INT1IF
        BCF INTCON, 7 ;Disable all interrupts inside interrupt service routine (disable GIEH)
        MOVLW 0x01
        BSF PORTD, 1
        goto prog

END
```

Answer (score 1):

So there are a couple things that need to change in your code. The microcontroller may be detecting the interrupt but your code doesn't handle it properly. When coding in ASM on the PIC family you have to take care of a lot of things manually. Interrupts in ASM require you to save the status and working registers before actually dealing with the interrupt. Normally you'd poll the peripheral flag but that's when you're dealing with multiple interrupts. Since you only have one we'll keep it simple.

At the start of the program, the usual way to tell the microcontroller to go to the main program is to put one `goto` after the `ORG 0x00`. So tidying up the initial parts of your code will yield:

```
    LIST    p=p18f45k50
    INCLUDE "p18f45k50.inc"

; Aim of program: input at B1 toggles the led at D1
; Assembly source line config statements

CONFIG  WDTEN = OFF   
CONFIG LVP = OFF 
CONFIG FOSC = INTOSCIO 

begin   
        ORG 0x00
        goto prog 

hinterrupt  
        ORG 0x08
        goto introutine

        ORG 0x22
prog    
        BCF INTCON3, 0 ;clear flag INT1IF 
        CLRF LATB ;clear latB
        ;D1
```

In your Interrupt Service Routine 'introutine'you used the `goto` instruction instead of the `retfie` instruction. Quoting the manual from section 10.3:

> The "return from interrupt" instruction, `retfie` exits the interrupt routine and sets the GIE/GIEH bit (GIEH/GIEL if priority levels are used), which re-enables interrupts.

So putting together all the information given so far your generic ISR follows this procedure:

1. Save status and working registers
2. Disable global interrupts for high and low levels
3. Poll interrupt-peripheral flag (if more than one interrupt)
4. Do user defined operation depending on if the flag is high or not
5. Clear interrupt-peripheral flag
6. Restore status and working registers
7. Exit ISR with `retfie`

The following ISR assumes you've already allocated a register for `W_TEMP` and `STATUS_T`

```
ISR
                MOVWF   W_TEMP      ; SAVE  W AND STATUS REGISTERS
                SWAPF   STATUS,W
                MOVWF   STATUS_T


                BCF INTCON, 7 ;Disable all interrupts inside interrupt service routine (disable GIEH)
                BCF INTCON3, 0 ;clear flag INT1IF
                MOVLW 0x01
                BSF PORTD, 1

                SWAPF   STATUS_T,W  ; RESTORE W AND STATUS REGISTERS
                MOVWF   STATUS
                SWAPF   W_TEMP,F
                SWAPF   W_TEMP,W

                RETFIE
```

The reason `movwf`and `swapf` are used is because those instructions do not modify the status of the Digit Carry, Zero or Carry Flags. It should also be noted that right now the ISR only turns on the LED and doesn't toggle it, that could be done with a simple XOR mask.

Lastly, since your whole program is interrupt driven, it would make sense to have the microcontroller in a loop after you've setup everything. Like this:`

```
    ***code from before**
    ;INT1 hence B1 settings
    BSF INTCON3, 6 ;set INT1 to high priority 
    BSF INTCON2, 5 ;+ve edge trigger for B1
    BSF INTCON3, 3 ;enable INT1
    BSF RCON, 7 ;set IPEN to HIGH thus enabling priorities on interrupts
    BSF INTCON, 7 ;set GIEH to high, enabling high priority interrupts
loop
        goto loop
```

This way after you've set up all the interrupts and the LED, the microcontroller stays in a loop and reacts only to the interrupt

Comment: I have followed your instructions but still no interrupt is being detected. Circuit is correct and pushbutton is getting a 5V Input following an RC circuit, I have even tried to physically move a wire connected to supply to RB1.

Comment: You're certain the configuration of the interrupts and the configuration bits are correct ?